# read custom tags props in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Im using code like this :

```
<li id="x" runat="server" code="myCode"> ...
```

Is it possible to iterate through each control on the site check if it has got code attribute and if yes process it it any way ?

thanks for help.

Im using asp.net 2.0
attempts in castings return null so that I dont have control over attributes

```
foreach (object control in this.Controls.ToString())
    {
        HtmlGenericControl gc = control as HtmlGenericControl;
        if(gc != null)
        {

            if(gc.Attributes["code"] != null) ...
```

the code below doesnt enter into if. All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HtmlControl` from which `HtmlGenericControl` derives, has a property `Attributes`.

That property is of type `AttributeCollection` and contains all the attributes the `HtmlControl` has.

You can access the attribute like this:

```
// in aspx
<li runat="server" id="MyLi" code="Test"></li>

// in code behind
var myCodeAttribute = MyLi.Attributes["code"];
```

Read more on that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.attributes.aspx

**EDIT:**

In order to iterate and conditionally determine what controls that have the special attribute you can do this:

in aspx

```
<ul runat="server" id="MyUl">
    <li runat="server" code="Test1"></li>
    <li runat="server" code="Test2"></li>
    <li runat="server" code="Test3"></li>
    <li runat="server" code="Test4"></li>
</ul>
```

in code behind

```
foreach (var control in MyUl.Controls)
{
   var htmlGenericControl = control as HtmlGenericControl;
   if (htmlGenericControl != null && htmlGenericControl.Attributes["code"] != null)
   {
      var myCodeAttribute = htmlGenericControl.Attributes["code"];        
   }
}
```

You probably want to tidy this up and break it out to methods and what not, but that I leave to you.

Comment: Ok but I want to find all controls which has got this attribute. lets say that I dont know their ids.

Comment: Once you have the `runat="server"` on an HTML tag, it becomes a `HtmlGenericControl` and you can work with in an object oriented manner. It's the same if you want to find all `Label` controls or whatever.